# OpenGL: glBindBuffer on generic binding point

Tags: opengl

I was reading the [documentation](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBindBuffer.xhtml) on glBindBuffer when I saw this:

> Likewise, the GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, GL_ATOMIC_COUNTER_BUFFER and GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER buffer binding points may be used, **but do not directly affect uniform buffer, atomic counter buffer or shader storage buffer state**, respectively.

What does "*do not directly affect uniform buffer, atomic counter buffer or shader storage buffer state*" mean?

I bound a buffer to the generic GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER binding point, and when querying for the state of SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER_BINDING, the previously bound buffer name is returned.

On [this](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/ARB/ARB_shader_storage_buffer_object.txt) site describing the shader_storage_buffer_object extension, it states that SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER_BINDING is part of the shader storage buffer state.

Therefore I believe that using glBindBuffer on a generic binding point (such as GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER) does indeed affect the shader storage buffer state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes obviously, if you bind the buffers to the context, you can query those bind points. But the point the docs is trying to get across is that those binding points *don't mean anything*.

Consider `GL_COPY_READ_BUFFER`. Binding to this target means something. If you call `glCopyBufferSubData`, it will use the buffer bound to `GL_COPY_READ_BUFFER` as the source buffer for that copy operation.

By contrast, there is no OpenGL operation that will use the buffer bound to `GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER` for any actual OpenGL operations. Sure, you can query it, but that's *all* you can do with it. If you want to use a buffer for actual storage buffer operations, you [must use `glBindBufferRange/Base` or equivalent functions](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Buffer_Object#Binding_indexed_targets).

Comment: If I bind a buffer to GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, calling glBufferData() with the target GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER will alter the buffer object bound to that binding point, no? Therefore one can say that it has a use. So the documentation intended to say that the generic binding point has no use for **shader storage buffer-specific** operations? If so, a better wording could have been chosen. One last thing, what do you mean by "*if you bind the buffers to the contents*"? Thank you.

Comment: @user42768: "*If so, a better wording could have been chosen.*" The wording is fine. It doesn't say that "uniform buffer binding state" is not affected. It just says "uniform buffer state" is unaffected. That is, state having to do with the use of a buffer object for uniform data.

Comment: But on [this site](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/ARB/ARB_shader_storage_buffer_object.txt) it explicitly says that "SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER_BINDING" is part of the "Shader Storage Buffer State". This is what made me think the wording is not exactly correct.

Comment: I looked at the [lastest official OpenGL specification (4.6 Core Profile)](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf) and the same table from https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/ARB/ARB_shader_storage_buffer_object.txt is now named "Shader Storage Buffer Binding State" (page 624). I was not able to find an explicit definition of "shader storage buffer state". I guess it means, like you said, a "logical state" which is strictly related to, in this specific instance, the *shader storage buffer*-specific operations.